# ArgumentException when accessing image in List containing more than 33k images

Tags: c#, image, winforms, gdi+, system.drawing

When you create a List with over 33000 images in it, and you try to access **a property** of the image at index 33000 or above, you get ArgumentException ("Paramether is not valid")  *at System.Drawing.Image.get_Width()
   at System.Drawing.Image.get_Size()
   at Test.Form1.OnLoad(EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\Test\Test\Form1.cs*

```
 List<Image> list = new List<Image>();
 for (int i = 0; i < 34000; i++)
 {
     list.Add(Resources.close);
 }

 System.Drawing.Size size = list[33333].Size;
```

The image is with size 32x32. Here is it:
[image]

[image]

It appears that when you have over 33k image objects you get this exception. According to MSDN you could have around 65k GDI objects: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724291(v=vs.85).aspx). Anyway does anyone know a way to workaround it and have a useful collection of multiple images in a single process?

Comment: Are you getting this exception with that *exact* code, or do you actually have different images for each entry in the list? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: You get the exception with this exact code.

Comment: Well, that's not enough for us to reproduce it without creating the image ourselves etc... are you able to reproduce this in a short but *complete* example, as I asked before? (I have time to copy/paste/compile/run, but not to start messing around in Visual Studio creating a new project etc.)

Comment: I have added the precise image.

Comment: That doesn't make it trivial for me to reproduce the problem though... My guess is that this is due to how many Windows handles can be open at a time. Can we ask why you really *need* that many images at once?

Comment: I am not sure why it is not trivial for you - it is couple lines of code and a single image. Could not be less than that. It related with the number of handles yes. I have a large data with 100k rows with data and images that I have to show in a grid and these images are different.

Comment: Close is propery. Each time accesing create new object. Why don't create it's copy  var closeImage = Resources.Close and use it?

Comment: "Could not be less than that." Yes, it could. In order to reproduce this, I have to open Visual Studio, create a new WinForms project, add a Form_Load event and copy in your code, download the file, add a resource. Compare that with what I was requesting: a short piece of code which I can copy from the question, paste into a new text file, compile, run, and see the error.

Comment: @JonSkeet This whole process will take less than a minute. No offence, but I think you are being picky. Feel free to skip my question, I will wait for other people to see it.
ArtavazdBalayan - because I can have different images, this is just for example.

Comment: Right, I will skip it... but you should be aware that by not putting the effort into making it easy for others to help you, you've limited how many people are going to be willing to put effort into helping you. I've managed to reproduce the problem in a complete application of 23 lines (which does still need the file, admittedly). But you've made it clear you don't value my help at this stage.

Comment: I think you should write your own image manager. It should control the number of loaded images. Also you should implement your own virtualization VirtualMode [https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.virtualmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx]. I'm sure that in the certain moment use can't see all 65536 images :) ImageManager will dynamically load needed images

Comment: "Help I will give" says Jon Skeet / OP says "No, get on your feet" / "Your help I don't need" / "Too picky indeed" / And gave no code that's complete

Comment: @ArtavazdBalayan that's definitely possible and this is how I workaround it. However, I was trying to see if something else can be done.